# Android: cannot access sdcard files from device

Tags: android, sd-card

I'm working on an android app that writes and reads .PNG files from sdcard. I've already tried it on a device (htc) and it was working fine. Then I had to modify some code to correct some  errors (Note that changes made had nothing to do with save/open function). But now just like that I can no longer save/open files on sdcard.

I've tried to open sdcard folder in DDMS File Explorer view (eclipse) but it appears empty and the permissions are `d---------`. I think it has something to do with the permissions but I have no idea what exactly is causing this problem and how to solve it.

To see if the problem was in my app I tested it on an emulator and it's working fine. So the problem is definitely related to the device.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you didn't connect the phone to your PC in "disk drive" mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem! I accidently selected "disk drive" mode. As it's my first app I didn't know it could cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recall that in order to be able to view contents of certain directories with ddms you need to have rooted your phone to get the permissions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually when my app was working fine I was able to open sdcard folder in DDMS that's why I tried to open it this time to see if my saved files were there but I can't.